# Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have read a lot of different posts trying to figure out why my code isn't working but the goal here is to set the value of the column 'name' to null when column 'mark' is below 69. My code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE gradesReport()
BEGIN
  SELECT name FROM students WHERE mark > 69;
  UPDATE students SET name = NULL WHERE mark < 69;
END
```

The first statement works fine but then I get the error that column name cannot be null.

Comment: Are you sure you want to erase the name? How would you know who the marks are for if you do so?

Comment: @AzizSaleh I am trying to hide their names when their mark is low.

Comment: I guess if you have NO USE for their names once they reach a low mark, then it could work (just make sure the column definition allows null). Another option is to have a `display_name` column which you use to display and erase that instead, while keeping track of the original name.

Comment: @AzizSaleh how would I go about writing the code for that? Would I run into the can't be null problem again?

Comment: If this is the "real" table, then don't! You'll lose the data for good! I'd rather suggest you handle that hiding of the name with a `CASE ... END` in the query for the report, like: `SELECT CASE WHEN mark >= 69 THEN name END name, mark FROM students;`

Comment: What about students whose mark is exactly equal to 69? You don't select them, and you don't clear their names.

Comment: @stickybit This is for CodeSignal, it's a challenge where you get fake information and you try and solve it. they gave me two tables and my goal is to order the information.

Comment: @Barmar Oh shoot, those students wouldn't be displayed if they were right at 69 so I'll change them to 70.

Comment: One of the tests should be `>=` or `<=`.

Comment: @MattBlackert: Well, then the designers probably had good reasons declaring `name NOT NULL`. I can only guess of course, but I wouldn't bet that they wanted to make altering the table part of the challenge... (as a designer of a real application most certainly wouldn't do too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way of making a column nullable in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE students MODIFY name VARCHAR(255);
```

Columns are nullable by default in MySQL, so we don't actually need to specify `NULL` in the alter statement.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the column `name` is declared as not null

You should firstly changed it into a `NOT NULL` Column

```
ALTER TABLE students 
CHANGE `name` varchar(255) NULL;
```